# Help with electronic circuit for a bracelet that reads state from rfid tag attached to it and lights up the corresponding LED

Tags: arduino, rfid, attiny, nfc

I'd like to make a bracelet which has an RFID tag and LEDs inside of it. I made a device
(using Arduino and rc522) that will categorise people's bracelets into one of 3 categories when it touches the RFID tag on the bracelet and writes that category(i.e 2). I want the bracelet to be able to read the category from the tag and light up the RGB LED to the corresponding colour(i.e light up green when priority is 1).
I tried some stuff with adafruit st25dv16 but I think rc522 isn't compatible. Could someone please help me figure this out. Maybe I can use attiny in it somehow? I'd like the bracelet to be relatively small and low power. Thank you.

Comment: You need to figure out where you are having a problem so we can help. Right now this is "design this for me" question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a system that supports NFC tag emulation mode and run it as a tag emulator

Answer (score 0):

The rc522 reader/writer does not support ISO 15xxx tags like the ST25DV16. It only supports ISO/IEC 14443 A/MIFARE and NTAG. You need a different module for reading and writing for your plan.

Other than that your idea is sound. The ST tag can be written via rfid and then whatever microcontroller on your bracelet like the attiny can read the eeprom via i2c or similar to detect a change and light whatever leds you want.